# Oracle - How to write Query to return column header name with pipe delimited?

Tags: oracle, header, pipe, delimited

I want a Query to return the header name with pipe delimited. I found some reference online but couldn't get exactly what I want.

I want something return like this, not need to output for a file, just a query result:

**column1|column2|column3|column4|.......|columnN**

I tried this:   SELECT /*delimited*/ from tableName where rownum<1; Run as script using F5.

"UPC","UPC_DESCRIPTION","ITEM_CODE","DEPT_CODE"

But the result is comma delimited and has the quotes enclosure. --I don't want it.

In fact I have so many columns, is there a easy way/simple query to return ALL header (pipe delimited) without manually type each?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: You can use `set sqlformat delimited |` instead of including the hint in the query (at least in recent versions of SQL Developer/SQLcl). Alas there doesn't seem to be any way to stop if including the double-quote enclosures - even though the equivalent export setting does. You can change them, but not remove them completely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you just do:

```
select col1 || '|' || col2 || '|' || col3 || '|' || col4 || '|' || col5
  from table;
```

You can produce your query:

```
select 'select ' || LISTAGG(column_name , ' || ''|'' || ') within group (order by column_id) || ' from my_table' 
  from user_tab_columns 
  where table_name = 'MY_TABLE';
```

If you would like to get only header for your data please do:

```
select LISTAGG(column_name, '|') within group (order by column_id)
      from user_tab_columns 
      where table_name = 'MY_TABLE';
```

Comment: In fact I have so many columns, is there a easy way to return ALL header without manually type each?

Comment: @JerryLi I've posted you query that will produce query with all columns.

Comment: @JerryLi I've added you also query to produce header line in case you need it.

Comment: Thanks, the second query you posted return exactly what I want.

Comment: In `LISTAGG()` it is likely that in most cases one would want the columns to appear in the order they appear in the table, and not in the alphabetical order of column names. That can be done easily - in ORDER BY, order by COLUMN_ID (rather than COLUMN_NAME).